# Dynamic Transformation Mechanismn

Tags: json, xml, parsing, data-structures, transformation

Im looking for a possiblity to change a data structure to a other data structure.
The user should be able to define a "Input Data Template" and  an "Output Data Template".
The template for the input contains an example of the expected incoming data. The user can also define variables which he can use in the output template to transfer the data.

Thats the task here is an example:

```
InputTemplate
<root>
  <node>%data%</node>
</root>
OutputTemplate
{
  "data":%data%"
}
```

The Input and the output can be any format a user design in his file. The main idea is to fill the variables to reuse them.

Anybody have ideas so solve this task?
Thanks for your help!

Best regards

Comment: Be more specific. Does the input always look like XML and the output always look like JSON? It sounds like you're asking, "If a user submits the inputs and outputs, my program will create the program to create that output from the input." This is impossible in the general case (or at least extremely hard, hence how anyone is employed in the technology industry).

Comment: That’s the idea that a user can say here is the template of  incoming data and I want this structure. I mean many things are static. The magic would be the usage of the variables

Comment: You've sketched the design of a new programming language, something a bit like XSLT. If you don't know how to start designing a programming language, and if you don't know how to start writing a compiler to implement it, then you need to sign up for a three-year computer science course: you won't get the answer in a couple of paragraphs on StackOverflow.